# Delphi mask for binary numbers

Tags: delphi, mask

I have StringGrid and want have in it cells only `1` or `0`. I try to use StringGridGetEditMask

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1GetEditMask(Sender: TObject; ACol,
  ARow: Integer; var Value: String);
begin
  Value := '0';
  if not (strToInt(Value) in [0,1]) then value := #0;
end;
```

But there I can input all numbers from 0 to 9. How I can filtering all numbers, except 0 and 1?

Comment: I don't get your code. If you assign the value `'0'` to `Value`, then surely `StrToInt(Value)` will equal `0`?

Comment: I convert value to integer and compare with 0 and 1. If value not 0 or not 1, value will equal empty char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your intention you will need to subclass the [`TStringGrid`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid) class and in such subclass assign to the inplace editor's e.g. [`OnKeyPress`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.OnKeyPress) event like shown in this interposer class:

```
type
  TStringGrid = class(Grids.TStringGrid)
  private
    procedure InplaceEditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  protected
    function CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TStringGrid }

function TStringGrid.CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit;
begin
  Result := inherited CreateEditor;
  TMaskEdit(Result).OnKeyPress := InplaceEditKeyPress;
end;

procedure TStringGrid.InplaceEditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if not (Key in [#8, '0', '1']) then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

Comment: Surely, you should prefer to use `CharInSet` instead of that `in` operator as the Unicode Delphi warning suggests, but I haven't used it here since you didn't tell us your Delphi version.

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood the [`OnGetEditMask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomDrawGrid.OnGetEditMask) event. `Value` isn't the new string, which you are allowed to alter, but a place where you should give the control a *mask*. Unfortunately, however, [edit masks](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.MaskUtils.TEditMask) do not allow the functionality you request.